# useradd -g option doesn't seem to be working

Tags: command-line, groups, useradd

I tried:

```
sudo useradd -s "/bin/false" -g [existingGroupName] [userNameToAdd]
```

After the command I looked it up in `/etc/group`, but the user is not in the `[existingGroupName]`. Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `/etc/group` shows the secondary group members (users), not primary ones.

`-g` in `useradd` sets the *primary group* the user would belong to, which must be only one; whereas `-G` adds user to single or multiple *secondary groups*.

You can check user's primary group (and secondary groups) along with IDs with the `id` command:

```
id <username>
```

As a side note, unless intentional, you should use the `adduser` Perl wrapper of `useradd` instead of using it directly.

Another note would be to use `getent group` instead of directly reading/parsing `/etc/group` for getting a group info e.g.:

```
getent group <group_name>
```

Comment: Oh, /etc/group is only for the secondary group members. Is there any file only for the primary member? Thanks for the tips, id and getent command as well.

Comment: @Smile Yes, `/etc/passwd` :)